# What is the difference in the function of tractus rubrospinalis and tractus corticospinalis?

Tags: human-biology, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

What is the difference in the function of tractus corticospinalis and tractus rubrospinalis? I know, that they begin in different parts of the brain, but from what have I read on the internet*, I can't see any difference in their function. The only difference I can see is, that tractus rubrospinalis is having impact only on the upper half of the body, but still this isn't difference in their function (at least on the upper part of the body).

Edit: 
* for the [rubrospinal tract I have read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubrospinal_tract)

> The tract is responsible for large muscle movement regulation flexor and inhibiting extensor tone as well as fine motor control.

and for the [corticospinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corticospinal_tract)

> The primary purpose of the corticospinal tract is for voluntary motor control of the body and limbs.

Both are from wikipedia, but this is just because it is was the fastest source of something in english. I learned it from sources in my language so I can't post them here, but I understood it very similarly as it is on the wikipedia.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a short quote (with references) on what you've read about each and why that makes you think it's the same?

Comment: @BryanKrause, sorry, rn I don't have time, but I'll do it about an hour later. BTW, I also don't think, that they do the same thing, I just also don't know what is the exact difference. This is the reason, why I am asking. Anyways, thanks for tip how to improve the question.

Comment: @ARogueAnt., humans, there is the `human-biology` tag.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd missed that.

Comment: Assuming those quotes are from Wikipedia (and wherever you quote from it's **always** important to cite your source), did you happen to read the sentence before the first one, and the paragraph after the second?

Comment: @BryanKrause, Yep I did. For the sentence, yes, it is smaller, but I am asking if (and if yes, what) there is something different in what kind of things they do, not just, that one is smaller and the other is bigger, so it can transfer more informations. And for the paragraph, yep, that is my mistake, I forgot to say it, but I am asking only on the motor part of it's function.

Comment: Before the first: "**It is one of the pathways for the mediation of involuntary movement**, along with other extra-pyramidal tracts including the vestibulospinal, tectospinal, and reticulospinal tracts." After the second: "After patients are lesioned in some part of the pyramidal tracts, they are paralyzed on the corresponding side of the body. However, they can re-learn some crude, basic motions, just no fine movements.[2] **This implies that the connections to these tracts are crucial for fine movement**, and only partial recovery is possible if they are damaged."

Comment: Oh sorry, so we were probably referencing to different senences. This is probably the answer, so thanks.